# Min and max number from every row in matrix

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

I have matrix, and the idea is to write a code that gives max and min number from every row, without any function, just pure logic.
For example:

Max Numbers should be:
567, 789, 900, 906, 897

Min Numbers should be:
45, 100, 191, 323, 101

```
[45, 456, 321, 344, 567],
[100, 434, 173, 400, 789],
[191, 211, 457, 809, 900],
[431, 323, 432, 805, 906],
[708, 232, 897, 101, 696]
```

```
$arrNxm = [
  [45, 456, 321, 344, 567],
  [100, 434, 173, 400, 789],
  [191, 211, 457, 809, 900],
  [431, 323, 432, 805, 906],
  [708, 232, 897, 101, 696]
];

$rows = 5;
$cols = 5;

$intValue = 1;

$max = $arrNxm[0][0];

for($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++)
{
  $max = $arrNxm[$row][0];
  for($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++)
  {
    if($arrNxm[$row][$col] > $max)
    {
      $max = $arrNxm[$row][$col];
    }
  }
}


echo "<pre>";
var_dump($max);
echo "</pre>";
```

When I run my code, I get only one number, and I cannot figure what I've suppose to do to get the right output.

Comment: First of all, it's max and min for every `row` and not `column` !

Comment: `var_dump($max)` in inner `for`.

Comment: A slight change would skip 1 more comparison, change inner loop to `for($col = 1` as you always set the value from 0 so why compare it against itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$arrNxm = [
  [45, 456, 321, 344, 567],
  [100, 434, 173, 400, 789],
  [191, 211, 457, 809, 900],
  [431, 323, 432, 805, 906],
  [708, 232, 897, 101, 696]
];

$row = 5;
$col = 5;
$min = $max = array();

for( $i = 0; $i < $row; $i++ ) {
    $min_val = $max_val = $arrNxm[ $i ][0];    
    for( $j = 0; $j < $col; $j++ ) {
        //echo $arrNxm[ $i ][ $j ]." ";
        if( $min_val > $arrNxm[ $i ][ $j ] ) {
            $min_val = $arrNxm[ $i ][ $j ];
        }

        if( $max_val < $arrNxm[ $i ][ $j ] ) {
            $max_val = $arrNxm[ $i ][ $j ];
        }
    }
    // echo $min_val.PHP_EOL;
    $min[] = $min_val;
    $max[] = $max_val;
}
print_r( $min );
print_r( $max );
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 45
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 191
    [3] => 323
    [4] => 101
)
Array
(
    [0] => 567
    [1] => 789
    [2] => 900
    [3] => 906
    [4] => 897
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rewritting the same variable with the max for each row. That's why in the end you will always have one number.

Instead you should make an array for results and store the max for each row separately like this:

```
$max = [];
for($row = 0; $row < $rows; $row++)
{
  $max[$row] = $arrNxm[$row][0];
  for($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++)
  {
    if($arrNxm[$row][$col] > $max[$row])
    {
      $max[$row] = $arrNxm[$row][$col];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With 2 foreach loops and a couple of terney if's

```
$arrNxm = [
  [45, 456, 321, 344, 567],
  [100, 434, 173, 400, 789],
  [191, 211, 457, 809, 900],
  [431, 323, 432, 805, 906],
  [708, 232, 897, 101, 696]
];

foreach ($arrNxm as $rkey => $row) {
    foreach ( $row as $ckey => $col) {
        // init this row in the results arrays
        if ($ckey == 0) { $min[$rkey] = PHP_INT_MAX; $max[$rkey] = 0; }              

        $min[$rkey] = $min[$rkey] > $col ? $col : $min[$rkey];
        $max[$rkey] = $max[$rkey] < $col ? $col : $max[$rkey];
    }
}

echo 'MAX' . PHP_EOL . print_r($max,1);
echo 'MIN' . PHP_EOL . print_r($min,1);
```

RESULT

```
MAX
Array
(
    [0] => 567
    [1] => 789
    [2] => 900
    [3] => 906
    [4] => 897
)
MIN
Array
(
    [0] => 45
    [1] => 100
    [2] => 191
    [3] => 323
    [4] => 101
)
```

Answer (score 0):

i would like to suggest this

```
$arrNxm = [
  [45, 456, 321, 344, 567],
  [100, 434, 173, 400, 789],
  [191, 211, 457, 809, 900],
  [431, 323, 432, 805, 906],
  [708, 232, 897, 101, 696]
];
$max = array();
$min = array();
foreach ($arrNxm as $key) {
    array_push($max, max($key));
    array_push($min, min($key));
}
```

Comment: Code it's okay, but if you look carefully my question, you will see that I mentioned that code needs to be written using only logic, without any array function.